# jetty-maven-plugin from mortbay to eclipse HTTPS setting

Tags: maven, jetty

I was using jetty-maven-plugin with groupId mortbay but I want to use the lastest Jetty version 9.

As we can see mortbay does not provides jetty version 9 http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-maven-plugin/
but eclipse yeah.

My previous pom.xml contains:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.9.v20130131</version>
    <configuration>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
        <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>8080</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector">
                <port>8443</port>
                <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                <keystore>/tmp/keystore</keystore>
                <password>jetty8</password>
                <keyPassword>jetty8</keyPassword>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-jetty</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <daemon>true</daemon>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-jetty</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But when I switch to eclipse

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
```

`<connectors>` are no more available.

Anyone can explain me how to configure SSL/HTTS using org.eclipse.jetty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector setup for jetty changed dramatically for Jetty 9 so the plugin configuration changed as well.

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html

Although if you are looking to setup ssl support (which I typically haven't seen since that is generally more of a production deployment thing then a development time thing) then you can look through the jetty-distribution for jetty-9 and piece together the configuration for the ssl connector into a jetty.xml file and use that with the  configuration property.

Looking through the documentation on this, we should show this as an example so I'll open a task to get that better documented, or perhaps add proper ssl configuration on the maven plugin.

Bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=408962

Feel free to comment on or follow that issue.

Comment: Thanks I had the same problem with you, missing documentation :) I will follow the issue.